# separate string by comma in java using regex

Tags: java

> Kh-H0f2ZNYcxWYQtJvA-4jQ2rnm8WQSsVsNFkVRMYxpg-1417365081517,38606,"Best
>   Buy Co, Inc.",BBY01-694284011841

expected ans is

> Kh-H0f2ZNYcxWYQtJvA-4jQ2rnm8WQSsVsNFkVRMYxpg-1417365081517 "Best Buy
>   Co, Inc." 
>   BBY01-694284011841

but i'm getting

> Kh-H0f2ZNYcxWYQtJvA-4jQ2rnm8WQSsVsNFkVRMYxpg-1417365081517
>   "Best Buy Co
>   Inc."
>   BBY01-694284011841

i used split

> String s="...";
>   String s[]=s.split(",");

Comment: same `variable` name for `String` and `Array`? Can you post your code?

Comment: "Best Buy Co, Inc." has a comma in it... maybe you should change it to a dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead for whitespace to avoid splitting `Best By Co` and `Inc.`:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        "Kh-H0f2ZNYcxWYQtJvA-4jQ2rnm8WQSsVsNFkVRMYxpg-1417365081517,38606,\"Best Buy Co, Inc.\",BBY01-694284011841"
        .split(",(?!\\s)")
    )
);
```

**Output**

```
[Kh-H0f2ZNYcxWYQtJvA-4jQ2rnm8WQSsVsNFkVRMYxpg-1417365081517, 38606, "Best Buy Co, Inc.", BBY01-694284011841]
```

Comment: That's true, though I suspect the question is rather "how do I avoid splitting on commas that are wrapped in quotes", rather than commas that are followed by whitespace.  It's a poor question, though.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle you make a good point. And yes, not a great question.